# What changed between kernels 3.7 and 3.9 that affects LVM/RAID root file systems?

Tags: linux-kernel, software-raid, kernel-panic, lvm, root-filesystem

I'm trying to fix a (very messy) system that the user hosed by running a kernel upgrade from 3.7.10 to 3.9.6. the root file system is on an LVM volume on top of a software RAID array. The boot manager is grub2.

The 3.9 kernel is unable to mount the root file system. It spits out the usual not-very-helpful bit about the device node not existing. This happens whether I use the UUID, the `/dev/{vg}/{lv}` or `/dev/mapper/{vg}-{lv}` notation for the root file system in the grub config file.

The 3.7 kernel on the other hand is still on the machine and actually mounts the root file system and boots up just fine. Unfortunatly the modules got removed so even the keyboard doesn't work. I can book it up to a rescue cd, in which case the RAID arrays and LVM volumns come up just fine.

Both kernels have matching `initrd` files that include the same set of modules. The initrd file is created by `genintrd` as part of the post-install process of the package manager<sup>1</sup>. LVM is built in and MD modules are present in the initrd. Further inspection<sup>2</sup> of the init file shows they have identical root fs paths, the same one grub is passing in.

I have tried searching around for the net for related issues but none of the cases out there seem to quite match this. I was unable to find anything about changes in the 3.9 kernel that would necesssitate a configuration change on the system from 3.7. What changed to the handling of LVM root file systems in 3.9?

<sub>1. The distro is PLD-Linux, an RPM based distro. Kernel packages are stock rpm's from the TH tree.</sub>
<sub>2. Inspected each one by extracting it using `gunzip | cpio -i` and observing module and script files.</sub>

Comment: Need not be a kernel problem. Are you sure that the 3.9 initrd has been built with MD and LVM support?

Comment: @HaukeLaging Yes, as a matter of fact I am. And inspection of the respective initrds shows it the LVM config data is the same between them both.

Comment: They should be aware that doing MD _and_ LVM is a bit redundant. LVM can do both on its own. Fewer component parts. If you've checked initrd, I'd also verify that the kernel arguments in grub for the new kernel don't specify something weird.

Comment: @JoelDavis Yes I'm aware of that :) And the kernel arguments in grub are identical for both kernels, no funky business there. I've tried a few funky things, but what works for 3.7 does not work for 3.9.

Comment: I use a similar setup myself (Root on LVM, LUKS, mdadm). Everything works fine for me using 3.9.x kernel. No changes were necessary. So it must be an issue with your configuration or your initramfs. Do you have a busybox shell, what happens when you enable LVM volumes there?

Comment: Are any of the PV's in the volume group coming in from a SAN or something like that? It's possible it's a driver issue (although that typically results in a different initrd, can you update the post with what you're doing to verify initrd contents?)

Comment: @frostschutz It is in fact busybox throwing the error about not being able to switch to newroot before the kernel panic, but I don't know how to drop to a busybox shell before that happens.

Comment: Add a `/bin/sh` or `/bin/busybox sh` into `/init` at the place where you want the shell. Also provide more info: which distro, what's creating the initramfs (you could try another generation tool such as `dracut` and see if that works), maybe even upload your kernel + initrd somewhere.

Comment: @JoelDavis I updated the post with my inspection method, and no there is not a SAN involved. All 5 devices involved are local SATA drives.

Comment: Well, I'm out of ideas but you might try [netconsole](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Boot_Debugging#Net_Console) to see if there's a descriptive error before the panic.

Comment: What makes you think that the kernel is the problem.  Maybe the specific module is the problem, or one of its various support packages.

Comment: @mdpc The options are pretty limited, there aren't a lot of players at this stage of the boot process. There aren't "support packages". We're talking about grub plus an initrd, at which point we can't mount a root file system. Even if the problem is in a module rather than the kernel itself, it's in one of a handful of core modules or the init script in the initrd.

Comment: Where did these kernels come from? Are they provided by your distribution (which one), or home-compiled? How are they configured (post both `config` files, or at least their diff)? Is there an initrd/initramfs, and has it been rebuilt properly after the kernel update?

Comment: @Gilles The initrd bit was already in my post. I'll come up with configs tomorrow along with trying drop to a shell before mounting root. I figured this would be an easy "oh the /dev/ paths changed from X to Y" sort of thing that I was just failing to use google effectivly for.

Comment: @Caleb It could be that the `/dev` paths changed because of some switch from udev to devtmpfs. We'd need to know the initramfs content and the kernel config to detect that.